# ruby session variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-test

I'm trying to write basic assert test:

```
def assert_session_has ( sessionvar )
    return assert_not_nil session[:sessionvar]
end
```

when I compile:

```
def test_auth_bob
    #some setup and other validation methods
    assert_not_nil session[user]
    #more validations...
end
```

I get the following error:

```
test_auth_bob(UserControllerTest):
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<UserControllerTest:0x3460c28>
/test/functional/user_controller_test.rb:23:in `test_auth_bob'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost a colon. As painful as that sounds, some people don't even notice.

```
def test_auth_bob
    #some setup and other validation methods
    assert_not_nil session[:user]
    #more validations...
end
```

Without the : user refers to a variable or method, with a colon user is the symbol :user. [This post on the internet about symbols](http://glu.ttono.us/articles/2005/08/19/understanding-ruby-symbols) appears to explain more… but I have not read it. I'm being called away from the computer by a thrilling but slow moving episode of The Wire. It's good.

Answer (score 2):

Where do you declare `user` in your `test_auth_bob` function?  The interpreter is complaining that the symbol is undefined.

Comment: line 23 is the assert_not_nil call. I know it is this line because if I comment it out the rest of the test function is fine.

Comment: Deleted my comment as I saw which line is 23 in the error message.

Comment: its not complaining about the test_auth_bob function

Comment: Your error message above says `user_controller_test.rb:23:in `test_auth_bob'`. Both the answer above and below seem to be valid, unless there is something I'm completely missing.